# The Brasilia Summer Time 2019 at JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have my datacenter in Brazil and all my JS applications have a Timezone problem because at 2019 the daylight save hour is not enable and the JS Server (NodeJS) understand the Brasil with -2 timezone but I need -3 .

I tried :

```js
console.log(new Date()); // Sun Nov 10 2019 11:09:35 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)
console.log(new Date().toISOString()); //2019-11-10T13:09:35.653Z
```

Comment: Have you tried starting Node applications with a timezone argument? `env TZ='America/Sao_Paulo' node server.js`

Comment: Yes, but in that example the error was the same. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll get the correct timezone offset if you upgrade your version of Node.js, it has been updated to reflect the timezone changes: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V12.md#12.13.1.

I believe Node 12.13.1 will show the correct UTC offset (-3 hours), e.g. in node 12.13.1 if I do:

```
console.log(new Date().toString());
```

I get

```
'Mon Dec 02 2019 11:28:26 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, when I upgraded the NodeJS the time is correctly now .

Comment: That's great! Europe will likely drop DST in 2021.. That will cause some problems too!