# Node using Brazil Summer Time in 2019

Tags: node.js, linux, timezone

I'm trying to use the NodeJS Date but it's returning the date with Brazilian Summer Time (-2) instead of the normal one (-3). This year Brazil will not have Summer Time, so it's supposed to be -3.

I tried: `new Date().toString()` in the Node REPL and the output has: `'Mon Dec 02 2019 11:22:28 GMT-0200 (Brasilia Summer Time)'`. I tried using a ENV to set the TZ to `America/Sao_Paulo` and the result was the same.

The time in my computer is -3 as it should be: if I run `date` in the terminal I got `Mon  2 Dec 10:23:15 -03 2019` and in the Python REPL the result is also correct.

Comment: btw, I saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58789061/the-brasilia-summer-time-2019-at-javascript but there's no working solution and the there's missing information in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest making sure you're running the latest Node.js version for either the LTS or current, e.g. 12.13.1+ or 13.2+

For LTS, I believe you want version 12.13.1, the changelog is here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V12.md#12.13.1, this shows the update for the Brazil DST change.

Since the DST changes were made in April 2019 (I believe), older Node versions cannot reflect them.

If I set my timezone to Brazil, and do the following (in Node 12.13.1):

```
console.log("Current time:", new Date().toString());
```

I get the output:

```
Current time: Mon Dec 02 2019 11:20:56 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
```

which is correct

However I get a UTC offset of -2 hours using Node 12.13.0.

I'd also suggest trying [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) and [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) if this isn't working, they have been updated to reflect the Brazilian DST changes, you can do:

```
console.log(moment("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z").tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format());
console.log(moment("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z").tz("America/Sao_Paulo").format());
```

This is giving me the results:

```
2019-05-31T21:00:00-03:00
2019-11-30T21:00:00-03:00
```

Which I believe is correct (UTC -3:00 for each)

You can also get the UTC offset from

```
console.log(moment.tz.zone("America/Sao_Paulo").utcOffset(new Date("2019-06-01T00:00:00Z").getTime())); 
console.log(moment.tz.zone("America/Sao_Paulo").utcOffset(new Date("2019-12-01T00:00:00Z").getTime()));
```

This should give 180 minutes for both Dec 1 and June 1 (this is actually the negative of UTC offset, this is due to the IANA timezone database, and it's easy to simply switch sign).